Abelian topological group which isn't a product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces
Are there any 'nice' abelian topological groups with homotopy type different from a product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces? One way to formalise what I'm aiming for by saying 'nice' would be that the underlying space is a connected CW-complex.
Every finite-dimensional CW-group (topological group with the underlying space a CW-complex) is a Lie group by Hilbert's Fifth Problem, so adding the connected and abelian condition leaves us with only $\mathbb{R}^n\times (S^1)^m$. Hence any example would have to be infinite-dimensional.

Have you seen this thread? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1965078/348926

This answers my question, thank you!
